# How calculate light level for opening?

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d

I build 3D model of cone. Currently I do light.

**Without light**
[image: My cone without light]

**With light**
[image: My cone without light]

*yellow dot* - the sun
*pink dots* - center of facet
*white dots* - ends of normals

```
var light = new BABYLON.Vector3(120, 100, 0);
...
var currentFace = mesh.Facets[indexFaces];
var pixelA = this.project(currentFace.A, transformMatrix);
var pixelB = this.project(currentFace.B, transformMatrix);
var pixelC = this.project(currentFace.C, transformMatrix);
var normal1 = BABYLON.Vector3.Cross(pixelA, pixelB);
var normal2 = BABYLON.Vector3.Cross(pixelB, pixelC);
var normal3 = BABYLON.Vector3.Cross(pixelC, pixelA);
var center = pixelA.add(pixelB).add(pixelC).scale(1 / 3);
var normal = normal1.add(normal2).add(normal3).scale(1 / 3);
var end = center.add(normal.scale(5));
...
var lightDirection = light.subtract(center);
normal.normalize();
lightDirection.normalize();
var ndotl Math.max(0, BABYLON.Vector3.Dot(normal, lightDirection));
```

What have I done wrong?
Thanks for advance!
P.S. For base I took this [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2013/06/13/tutorial-series-learning-how-to-write-a-3d-soft-engine-from-scratch-in-c-typescript-or-javascript.aspx).

**UPDATE-1**

I rewrote my render method  and now It work much better, then before:

```
    Device.prototype.render = function (cfg, mesh) {
        var self = this,
            normals = [], normal, center, end, color, ndotl, light = cfg.light.clone(),
            pixelA, pixelB, pixelC, pixelWorldA, pixelWorldB, pixelWorldC, normalA, normalB, normalC,
            viewMatrix, projectionMatrix, worldMatrix, worldViewTransformation, transformMatrix;
        viewMatrix = BABYLON.Matrix.LookAtLH(cfg.camera.position, cfg.camera.target, BABYLON.Vector3.Up());
        projectionMatrix = BABYLON.Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH(
            cfg.perspective.fov / 180,
            cfg.perspective.aspect,
            cfg.perspective.znear,
            cfg.perspective.zfar,
            cfg.perspective.distance);
        worldMatrix = BABYLON.Matrix.RotationYawPitchRoll(
            cfg.rotation.y / 180,
            cfg.rotation.x / 180,
            cfg.rotation.z / 180).multiply(BABYLON.Matrix.Translation(
                cfg.translation.x,
                cfg.translation.y,
                cfg.translation.z));
        worldViewTransformation = worldMatrix.multiply(viewMatrix);
        transformMatrix = worldViewTransformation.multiply(projectionMatrix);
        mesh.facets.forEach(function (facet) {
            pixelA = self.project(facet.a, transformMatrix);
            pixelB = self.project(facet.b, transformMatrix);
            pixelC = self.project(facet.c, transformMatrix);
            pixelWorldA = BABYLON.Vector3.TransformCoordinates(facet.a, worldViewTransformation);
            pixelWorldB = BABYLON.Vector3.TransformCoordinates(facet.b, worldViewTransformation);
            pixelWorldC = BABYLON.Vector3.TransformCoordinates(facet.c, worldViewTransformation);
            normalA = BABYLON.Vector3.Cross(pixelWorldA, pixelWorldB);
            normalB = BABYLON.Vector3.Cross(pixelWorldB, pixelWorldC);
            normalC = BABYLON.Vector3.Cross(pixelWorldC, pixelWorldA);
            center = pixelA.add(pixelB).add(pixelC).scale(1 / 3);
            normal = normalA.add(normalB).add(normalC).scale(1 / 3);
            end = center.add(normal.scale(20000));
            normals.push({start: center, end: end});
            ndotl = self.computeNDotL(center, normal, light);
            color = new BABYLON.Color4(ndotl * facet.color.r, ndotl * facet.color.g, ndotl * facet.color.b, ndotl * facet.color.a);
            self.drawTriangle(pixelA, pixelB, pixelC, color);
        });
        self.present();
        self.workingContext.fillStyle = "yellow";
        self.workingContext.fillRect(light.x - 10, light.y - 10, 20, 20);
        self.workingContext.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
        normals.forEach(function (p) {
            var p1 = p.start;
            var p2 = p.end;
            self.workingContext.beginPath();
            self.workingContext.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
            self.workingContext.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
            self.workingContext.stroke();
            self.workingContext.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
            self.workingContext.fillRect(p1.x - 2, p1.y - 2, 5, 5);
            self.workingContext.fillStyle = "#ff00ff";
            self.workingContext.fillRect(p2.x - 2, p2.y - 2, 5, 5);
        });
    };
```

In this code I added worldview Matrix.
My current result:

[image]

You said, to be hide the red area inside of cone, I can use z-buffer.
But... How?

Comment: My bet is your normal and light are the other way around in your coordinate system so just try `var ndotl Math.max(0, - BABYLON.Vector3.Dot(normal, lightDirection));` ... just added the minus sign. Also do you use the `ndot` ilumination intensity in rendering? (you should multiply the color of face by it and render the face)

Answer (score 0):

@Spektre,

> Also do you use the ndot ilumination intensity in rendering?

yes, I do that:

```
var c = new BABYLON.Color4(ndotl * currentFace.Color.r, ndotl * currentFace.Color.g, ndotl * currentFace.Color.b, 1.0);
this.drawTriangle(pixelA, pixelB, pixelC, c);
```

> just added the minus sign.

don't affected

If I be change my code so, then light there is, but it does not work properly

```
for (var indexFaces = 0; indexFaces < mesh.Facets.length; indexFaces++) {
    var currentFace = mesh.Facets[indexFaces];
    var pixelA = this.project(currentFace.A, transformMatrix);
    var pixelB = this.project(currentFace.B, transformMatrix);
    var pixelC = this.project(currentFace.C, transformMatrix);
    var normal1 = BABYLON.Vector3.Cross(currentFace.A, currentFace.B);
    var normal2 = BABYLON.Vector3.Cross(currentFace.B, currentFace.C);
    var normal3 = BABYLON.Vector3.Cross(currentFace.C, currentFace.A);
    normal1 = BABYLON.Vector3.TransformCoordinates(normal1, worldMatrix);
    normal2 = BABYLON.Vector3.TransformCoordinates(normal2, worldMatrix);
    normal3 = BABYLON.Vector3.TransformCoordinates(normal3, worldMatrix);
    var center = pixelA.add(pixelB).add(pixelC).scale(1 / 3);
    var normal = normal1.add(normal2).add(normal3).scale(1 / 3);
    var end = center.add(normal.scale(10000));
    centers.push({p1: center, p2: end});
    var ndotl = this.computeNDotL(center, normal, cfg.light);
    var c = new BABYLON.Color4(ndotl * currentFace.Color.r, ndotl * currentFace.Color.g, ndotl * currentFace.Color.b, 1.0);
    //console.log("center:"+center+", angle: " + (ndotl * 180) + ", cos: " + ndotl + ", type: " + currentFace.Type + ", color:" + c);
    this.drawTriangle(pixelA, pixelB, pixelC, c);
}
```

[image]

To calculate of the normal, I must use the points of original model(before applying transformations) or after(in my case, this points: pixelA, pixelB, pixelC)?

Comment: you should move this to your question as an edit not post as answer.... the @notification works only in comments. this image looks OK to me, may be you want to add some ambient light.... `c=face_color*(c_ambient+c_diffuse*ndotl)` where ambient is around 25% and diffuse 75%. or use `abs(ndotl)` to have double sided polygons (but that is usually not used with solids

Comment: also you should draw only the normals that are in view (based on polygon winding or Z-Buffer)

Comment: you can calculate normal when you want but the dot product must be done on vectors in the same coordinate system ... so either use local coordinate system but you need to transform the light position into it or use global coordinate system but then you need to use A,B,C transformed to it... If you got stacked all transforms to one then you got screen space coordinates after transform and need to transform the light position too ...

Comment: Can you explain me, how I can use z-buffer to be hiddent facets inside of cone?

Comment: Z-buffer `zed` is another screen (2D array) that just stores Z-coordinate of pixel instead of Color of pixel. It has the same resolution as rendering screen (`scr`). Before rendering you fill it with farest possible Z value from camera (for 32bit  int `0x7FFFFFFF`). Then change your `setpixel(x,y,color)` from `scr[y][x]=color` to something like `void setpixel(int x,int y,int z,DWORD color) { if (zed[y][x]>=z) { zed[y][x]=z; scr[y][x]=color; }}` so it renders only the visible pixels from camera ...

Comment: Also you can use `>=` in the if but in that case you need to clear with `-0x80000000` ... also you can add test for near and far z planes if you got perspective projection ...